# How to rotate a dynamically created ListBoxItem on a Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, rotation

In my WPF MVVM application I have a `ListBox` with `Canvas` as its `ItemsPanel`. The ListBox's items are dynamically created by the user when he clicks a button - the `ListBox.ItemsSource` is a list of items of my custom type stored in my `MainViewModel` which is the `DataContext` of my `MainWindow`. I would like the user to be able to rotate items using a set of `Thumb` controls attached to every `ListBoxItem`. So far I've had little success attempting to find a workable solution and I'm getting quite desperate.

Here's the most important part of my `ListBoxItem`'s Style:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
  <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width}"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height}"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
             <Grid>
                <Control Name="RotateDecorator"   
                         Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"
                         Template="{StaticResource RotateDecoratorTemplate}"
                         Visibility="Visible"/>
                          <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" />
             </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

And here you can see how it looks like: http://screenshooter.net/100101493/dhokpue

The `RotateDecorator` is essentially merely a set of slightly customized `Thumb` controls (displayed as the little triangles around the selected item in the picture) which I'd like to rotate my `ListBoxItem`. But I've completely run out of ideas on how to do this. The only thing I know is that I need to write suitable `DragDelta` and `DragStarted` methods to serve as event handlers. Any ideas that could ease my exasperation?

EDIT: Here are the `DragStarted` and `DragDelta` methods of the `RotationThumb`. Could they affect the way the moving Thumb is acting?

DragStarted:

```
private void RotateThumb_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        var thumb = sender as RotateThumb;
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(thumb);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        this.designerItem = parent as ListBoxItem;

        if (this.designerItem != null)
        {
            this.designerCanvas = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this.designerItem) as Canvas;

            if (this.designerCanvas != null)
            {
                this.centerPoint = this.designerItem.TranslatePoint(
                    new Point(this.designerItem.Width * this.designerItem.RenderTransformOrigin.X,
                              this.designerItem.Height * this.designerItem.RenderTransformOrigin.Y),
                              this.designerCanvas);

                Point startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this.designerCanvas);
                this.startVector = Point.Subtract(startPoint, this.centerPoint);

                this.rotateTransform = this.designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
                if (this.rotateTransform == null)
                {
                    this.designerItem.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0);
                    this.initialAngle = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        this.initialAngle = this.rotateTransform.Angle;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

DragDelta:

```
private void RotateThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.designerItem != null && this.designerCanvas != null)
        {
            Point currentPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this.designerCanvas);
            Vector deltaVector = Point.Subtract(currentPoint, this.centerPoint);

            double angle = Vector.AngleBetween(this.startVector, deltaVector);

            RotateTransform rotateTransform = this.designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
            rotateTransform.Angle = this.initialAngle + Math.Round(angle, 0);
            this.designerItem.InvalidateMeasure();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2: Problems Solved**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, but here is some pseudo-code that might get you started:

```
// for every drag event
Point a = listboxitem center position (or wherever you want the rotation origin)
Point b = position before drag
Point c = position after drag

// calculate and normalize vectors a-b and a-c
Vector v1 = ( b - a ).Normalized();
Vector v2 = ( c - a ).Normalized();

// calculate angles for v1 and v2 (in radians)
double a1 = Math.Atan2( v1.y, v1.x );
double a2 = Math.Atan2( v2.y, v2.x );

// the amount of rotation is then the difference between a1 and a2
// NOTE: there's a catch here, Atan2 returns angles = -π ≤ θ ≤ π, so
// the values might wrap around, which you'll need to take care of too
double angleInRadians = a2 - a1;
double angleInDegrees = ( angleInRadians / Math.PI ) * 180.0;
```

Then add this angle to the angle of a `RotateTransform` you put on the `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: Thanks! I've had access to similar code before (I'm using a sample found on the internet), and I've managed to get it to work, however, another problem appeared. When I rotate the item upside down, the Thumb responsible for moving the item around goes crazy  - gets very sensitive, moves the item in the opposite direction and swipes it out of the Canvas. In its DragDelta I simply update item's X and Y properties by e.HorizontalChange and e.VerticalChange accordingly. The only difference is that the moving Thumb is placed in the DataTemplate for my custom type. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Hmm. Is the `DragDelta` given in the thumb's rotated coordinate system maybe?

Comment: Hmm, as you can see in the style above, there is a binding between my custom item class' X and Y properties and `Canvas.Left/Canvas.Right` properties of a `ListBoxItem`. It's the coordinates of my custom object that are updated when the item is moved. Is it possible that the rotation affects the way in which the coordinates are interpreted by canvas? Anyway, I've included the `DragDelta` and `DragStared` code in the question and would appreciate if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Can you include commands and an angle property in your custom item class?

If so, bind the template rotate transform to the angle property and create commands that increase and decrease the angle.

Comment: I could do that, yes, that's an interesting idea. I'll keep it in mind for the future, thanks!